# Setting Base Application Path For File Include

Tags: php, codeigniter, include, codeigniter-2

I have read similar topics on StackOverflow but unfortunately none addressed this issue (or maybe I just didn't look at the right topics).

I have the following in the view `home.php`:

```
<?php include_once(echo base_url() .'/template/layout/header.php'); ?>
```

Now my structure is like this:

```
/public_html
    /template
    /layout
       /header.php
       /footer.php
```

The file is not including, does anyone know why?

**Note:** I have set `$config['base_url']` to `www.domain.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation `base_url()`:

> This function returns the same thing as `site_url()`, without the
>   index_page or url_suffix being appended.

So it should be returning `http://www.domain.com/` which would be wrong to use in `include_once()`

What you want to use is the CI constant `APPPATH`:

```
<?php include_once(APPPATH . 'template/layout/header.php'); ?>
```

As mentioned before you should be putting your views in your views folder and loading them instead of including them. That is the correct CI method to do so.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put your views under `/application/views/` and then you load them like this?

```
$this->load->file('application/views/layout');
$this->load->view('layout.php');
```

anyway you have to do:

```
<?php include_once(base_url().'/template/layout/header.php'); ?>
```

and not:

```
<?php include_once(echo base_url() .'/template/layout/header.php'); ?>
```

Comment: okay I tried that it worked in one place but not in another. is this normal? I tried <link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo base_url(); ?>application/views/css/grid-12.css" type="text/css">
and it didnt show

Comment: remove application from that path.

Comment: @sys_debug you need a `/` before `application` like so `... echo base_url(); ?>/application...`

Comment: before I remove application it loaded the content of header but not css or js. after removing same thing exactly. I also tried adding / or removing it, neither worked :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include_once(echo base_url() .'/template/layout/header.php'); ?>
```

Here you are doing 2 things wrong.

1. The code should not have echo inside include_once. So your code should be

> include_once(base_url() .'/template/layout/header.php');

1. You are trying to load a file using the url instead of absolute path. You can not include a file using base_url(which returns the site url http://www.domain.com/), if the php.ini allow_url_open is set to off.

You can get the absolute path to base using str_replace(SYSDIR.'/', '',BASEPATH)

So the below code will work:

```
$abs_path = str_replace(SYSDIR.'/', '',BASEPATH);
include_once($abs_path .'/template/layout/header.php');
```

As it is said in above 2 posts the correct way to do this in CI is by putting it inside view folder and load it using CI load function.